# Repositioning side by side elements for responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to adapt a website I have built for mobile/tablet viewing. I currently have three image & aside 'pairs' where the layout for each alters from image on the left to aside on the right, then image on the right and aside on the left.

I would now like to adapt this so that the aside sections wrap under each corresponding image for mobile layout. I've come a little bit stuck so would appreciate the best practice for implementing my desired layout.

Below are the appropriate code snippets. (The blank spaces are where the images appear.)

```css
.about-text {
  padding: 5% 5% 0 5%;
}

.def-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

#experience article {
  float: left;
}

#experience aside {
  float: right;
}

#gas-safe article {
  float: left;
}

#gas-safe aside {
  float: right;
}

#gas-safe a {
  color: #4E6E9B;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #4E6E9B;
}

#quality article {
  float: left;
}

#quality aside {
  float: right;
}

#to-top {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4E6E9B;
}

#to-top i {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#to-top:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="alt-color">
  <section class="table" id="experience">
    <article class="def-width">
      <img src="img/boiler-commission-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
    </article>
    <aside class="about-text def-width">
      <h2>34 Years Experience</h2>
      <p>Wayne is proud to have 34 years of experience in the gas engineering industry after having formerly completed a 3 year apprenticeship with British Gas.</p>
    </aside>

  </section>

  <section class="table" id="gas-safe">

    <article class="about-text def-width">
      <h2>Gas Safe Accredited</h2>
      <p>Safety always comes first. That's why we are trained to conform with the latest 'Gas Safe Register' standards.
      </p><br>

      <a href="https://www.gassaferegister.co.uk/find-an-engineer/check-a-business/?id=Wk%2biWbZCWcWz04dI3rDbQA%3d%3d" target="_blank">Check our Gas Safe Registration</a>

    </article>
    <aside class="def-width">
      <img src="img/radiator-fitting-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
    </aside>

  </section>

  <section class="table" id="quality">
    <article class="def-width">
      <img src="img/gas-engineer-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
    </article>
    <aside class="about-text def-width">
      <h2>Quality. Without Compromise.</h2>
      <p>Your central heating system is a big investment. We promise to only use industry leading products and install these with quality in mind; no corner cutting.</p>
    </aside>
  </section>

  <a id="to-top" href="index.html">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: you'd want to use [CSS @media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for better RWD

Comment: when you are talking about responsive-design, you are suppose to use bootstrap!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself very clear. I am already using media queries, however I have supplied the standard CSS to give clarity on how it is currently styled and therefore how to move forward with the styling to apply to the media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for responsive design check below snippet, which solve your problem easily with out [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

```css
.about-text {
  padding: 5% 5% 0 5%;
}

#gas-safe a {
  color: #4E6E9B;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #4E6E9B;
}   

#to-top {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4E6E9B;
}

#to-top i {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#to-top:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container alt-color">
  <div class="row">
    <section id="experience">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <article class="def-width">
          <img src="img/boiler-commission-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <aside class="about-text def-width">
          <h2>34 Years Experience</h2>
          <p>Wayne is proud to have 34 years of experience in the gas engineering industry after having formerly completed a 3 year apprenticeship with British Gas.</p>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section id="gas-safe">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <article class="about-text def-width">
          <h2>Gas Safe Accredited</h2>
          <p>Safety always comes first. That's why we are trained to conform with the latest 'Gas Safe Register' standards.
          </p><br>

          <a href="https://www.gassaferegister.co.uk/find-an-engineer/check-a-business/?id=Wk%2biWbZCWcWz04dI3rDbQA%3d%3d" target="_blank">Check our Gas Safe Registration</a>

        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <aside class="def-width">
          <img src="img/radiator-fitting-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
        </aside>
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <section id="quality">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <article class="def-width">
          <img src="img/gas-engineer-scaled.jpg" class="about-img">
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <aside class="about-text def-width">
          <h2>Quality. Without Compromise.</h2>
          <p>Your central heating system is a big investment. We promise to only use industry leading products and install these with quality in mind; no corner cutting.</p>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <a id="to-top" href="index.html">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap itself uses @media queries. While using Bootstrap is indeed a good solution and it makes life easier but sometimes we can avoid it (plus there are other lighter libraries if we want less features).

Comment: of course i accept all responsive libraries uses media queries. I suggest bootstrap as because its widely used and highly browser supported.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! This is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I haven't yet looked into bootstrap as I am only a beginner, however, having inspected various websites source code the use of bootstrap now looks familiar. Is this commonly used on the web for a range of different professional websites? I shall start doing some research into this!

Comment: obviously you are suppose to. It's a widely used library for responsive designing. you can check here for complete tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Comment: My only thought is, if I were to stretch the window to 1024px width for instance. Would my image/aside combinations return back to being side by side or is this permanently changing the layout to a vertical stack?

Comment: learn the basic of bootstrap then you will come to know why it is happening. Here I set an example which will be looking similar design in desktop and tablet views. Only on mobile view it will be coming one below another.

Comment: Mark it as answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Just add this media query to the top of your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  .about-text.def-width {
    width: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    float: left !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference to the output unfortunately.The use of bootstrap has been suggested though which seems to work perfectly. I really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're trying to do by using `@media-queries`. I had to modify your HTML slightly because the picture in the second row came after the content.

Currently, it's set to switch the layout at `800px` but you can alter than easily by modifying the `max-width` value in the CSS.

```css
.about-text {
  padding: 5% 5% 0 5%;
}

.def-width {
  width: 50%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
}

#experience article {
  float: left;
}

#experience aside {
  float: right;
}

#gas-safe article {
  float: left;
}

#gas-safe aside {
  float: right;
}

#gas-safe a {
  color: #4E6E9B;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #4E6E9B;
}

#quality article {
  float: left;
}

#quality aside {
  float: right;
}

#to-top {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4E6E9B;
}

#to-top i {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

#to-top:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .hide-desktop {
display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .hide-mobile {
display: none;
  }
  #gas-safe article {
float: none;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
  }
  #experience article,
  .table aside {
float: none !important;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
  }
  #quality article {
float: none;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="alt-color">
  <section class="table" id="experience">
<article class="def-width">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="about-img">
</article>
<aside class="about-text def-width">
  <h2>34 Years Experience</h2>
  <p>Wayne is proud to have 34 years of experience in the gas engineering industry after having formerly completed a 3 year apprenticeship with British Gas.</p>
</aside>

  </section>

  <section class="table" id="gas-safe">
<article class="def-width hide-desktop">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="about-img">
</article>
<article class="about-text def-width">
  <h2>Gas Safe Accredited</h2>
  <p>Safety always comes first. That's why we are trained to conform with the latest 'Gas Safe Register' standards.
  </p>
  <br>

  <a href="https://www.gassaferegister.co.uk/find-an-engineer/check-a-business/?id=Wk%2biWbZCWcWz04dI3rDbQA%3d%3d" target="_blank">Check our Gas Safe Registration</a>

</article>
<aside class="def-width hide-mobile">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="about-img">
</aside>

  </section>

  <section class="table" id="quality">
<article class="def-width">

  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200" class="about-img">
</article>
<aside class="about-text def-width">
  <h2>Quality. Without Compromise.</h2>
  <p>Your central heating system is a big investment. We promise to only use industry leading products and install these with quality in mind; no corner cutting.</p>
</aside>
  </section>

  <a id="to-top" href="index.html">
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i>
  </a>

</div>
```